# Dot graph generation too long around 60 edges

Tags: graphviz, dot, schemacrawler

I tried to get a MPD from an Oracle database using SchemaCrawler.
This tool generated a dot file and then use dot to generate the graph.

But after an hour, the processing still didnt finish so I tried to launch myself dot on my dot file with the following command :

**dot -v -Tpng schemacrawler.7007049984130928063.dot > graph.png**

In the following dot file I tried reducing the amount of edges and around 60 edges it last 2 minutes, over that it never finishes. => File : http://pastebin.com/Wvup5NTF

I get the following trace :

```
C:\dev\softs\schemacrawler-oracle-10.08.02>dot -v -Tpng schemacrawler.7007049984130928063.dot > graph.png

dot - graphviz version 2.30.1 (20130214.1330)

libdir = "C:\dev\softs\graphviz"

Activated plugin library: gvplugin_pango.dll

Using textlayout: textlayout:cairo

Using render: cairo:cairo

Using device: png:cairo:cairo

Activated plugin library: gvplugin_dot_layout.dll

Using layout: dot:dot_layout

The plugin configuration file:...

network simplex:  28 nodes 80 edges maxiter=2147483647 balance=2
```

After that, nothing.
Is there a way to make it faster and able to manage such amount of nodes and edges  (which is not that high from my opinion) ?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you are using Windows, and GraphViz has performance problems. You will have to use a very old version of GraphViz. I would suggest 2.28.0. http://www.graphviz.org/pub/graphviz/stable/windows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your Graphviz. I tried the file and it worked fine for me. Here's the verbose output:

```
dot - graphviz version 2.36.0 (20140111.2315)
Using render: cairo:cairo
Using device: png:cairo:cairo
libdir = "/usr/local/lib/graphviz"
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_dot_layout.6.dylib
Using layout: dot:dot_layout
The plugin configuration file:
    /usr/local/lib/graphviz/config6
        was successfully loaded.
    render  :  cairo dot fig map pic pov ps quartz svg tk vml xdot
    layout  :  circo dot fdp neato nop nop1 nop2 osage patchwork sfdp twopi
    textlayout  :  textlayout
    device  :  bmp canon cgimage cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot eps exr fig gif gv icns ico imap imap_np ismap jp2 jpe jpeg jpg pct pdf pic pict plain plain-ext png pov ps ps2 psd sgi svg svgz tga tif tiff tk vml vmlz x11 xdot xdot1.2 xdot1.4 xlib
    loadimage   :  (lib) bmp eps gif jpe jpeg jpg pdf png ps svg
fontname: "Helvetica" resolved to: (ps:pango  Helvetica,  REGULAR) (PangoCairoCoreTextFont) "Helvetica" 
network simplex:  28 nodes 27 edges maxiter=2147483647 balance=2
network simplex: 28 nodes 27 edges 0 iter 0.00 sec
network simplex:  4 nodes 4 edges maxiter=2147483647 balance=2
network simplex: 4 nodes 4 edges 0 iter 0.00 sec
network simplex:  1 nodes 0 edges maxiter=2147483647 balance=1
network simplex: 1 nodes 0 edges 0 iter 0.00 sec
Maxrank = 0, minrank = 0
mincross: pass 0 iter 0 trying 0 cur_cross 0 best_cross 0
mincross SchemaCrawler_Diagram: 0 crossings, 0.00 secs.
network simplex:  1 nodes 0 edges maxiter=2147483647 balance=2
network simplex: 1 nodes 0 edges 0 iter 0.00 sec
routesplines: 0 edges, 0 boxes 0.00 sec
Using render: cairo:cairo
Using device: png:cairo:cairo
dot: allocating a 601K cairo image surface (312 x 493 pixels)
gvRenderJobs SchemaCrawler_Diagram: 0.10 secs.
```

Here's the image that got generated:

[image: dot output]